# Wordpress sorting makes data disapear

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-4.0

```
$args = array("post_type" => 'groupmembers');
```

Gives me un-ordered custom post types

```
$args = array("post_type" => 'groupmembers',
               'meta_key' => 'display-order',
               'orderby' => 'meta_value_num');
```

Don't give me nothing, not even an error message. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is right answer

```
$args = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'groupmembers',
        'meta_key' => 'display-order',
        'orderby' => 'position'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the field 'display-order' displays the order number you want them to appear in, then you should be able to use:

```
$args = array("post_type" => 'groupmembers',
               'orderby' => 'display-order',
               'order' => 'ASC');
```

**EDIT**

Looked into it again and the following works for me (i used advanced custom fields to create the field, and worked with both text and number field - [plugin link](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)):

```
<?php $loopName = new WP_Query(
    array(
      'post_type' => 'groupmembers',
      'meta_key' => 'display-order',
      'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
      'order' => 'ASC',
    )
  );
?>
<?php while ( $loopName->have_posts() ) : $loopName->the_post(); ?>

  <!-- Do Stuff -->

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: That made the posts to display, but not in the correct order :(